# How to custom sort and add cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet w/hundreds of records. Column "C" has the name of that specific account. Column "D" has the amount that should be applied to that account. *note column "C" can have repeated values.

Column "M" has a list of all possible names that could appear in column "C" and column "N" has a number 1-???? in the order these items should be grouped by after being added in sheet2.

Ex:

```
Column C Column D                 Column M   Column N
John      $500                    John       1 
Jane     -$600                    Jane       2 
Jack      $250                    Jack       3
Jane      $45.00                  Joe        4
Joe                               Jay        5
Jack      $0.00                   Jayson     6
Jay       $85                     Jill       7
```

Sheet 2 should have the data above put in order by column "N" and added

Comment: Have you had a go at this yourself? If so, could you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Further code please?

Answer (score 0):

Seem like a Pivot-Table to me.
Numbering in the first column is just a chain of "IF"s
Data-Source of the Pivot is: Tabelle1!$B$4:$D$10
[image]

e.g. B5:    `=IF(C5=$F$5;$G$5;IF(C5=$F$6;$G$6;IF(C5=$F$7;$G$7;IF(C5=$F$8;$G$8;IF(C5=$F$9;$G$9;IF(C5=$F$10;$G$10;IF(C5=$F$11;$G$11;"")))))))`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, namesRng As Range, dataRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- reference "Sheet1" (change "Sheet1" to your actual data sheet name)
        Set dataRng = .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2) '<--| set the data range from cell "C1" to column "D" cell in column "C" last non empty row
        With .Range("M1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)  '<-- reference names/order range from cell "M1" to column "N" cell in column "M" last non empty row
            .Sort key1:=.Range("B1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo '<-- sort names in column "M" by column "N" order number
            Set namesRng = .Columns(1).Cells '<-- set ordered names range
        End With
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<-- reference "Sheet2" (change "Sheet2" to your actual output sheet name)
        For Each cell In namesRng '<-- loop through ordered name range
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 2).Value = Array(cell.Value, WorksheetFunction.SumIf(dataRng.Columns(1), cell.Value, dataRng.Columns(2))) '<--| write current name in Sheet2 column "A" current empty cell after last not empty one, and corresponding sum in adjacent cell
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

if names in column "M" are always already properly ordered, then there's no need to sort them by column "N" and the code slightly simplifies to:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, namesRng As Range, dataRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- reference "Sheet1" (change "Sheet1" to your actual data sheet name)
        Set dataRng = .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2) '<--| set the data range from cell "C1" to column "D" cell in column "C" last non empty row
        Set namesRng = .Range("M1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp)) '<-- set ordered names range
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<-- reference "Sheet2" (change "Sheet2" to your actual output sheet name)
        For Each cell In namesRng '<-- loop through ordered name range
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 2).Value = Array(cell.Value, WorksheetFunction.SumIf(dataRng.Columns(1), cell.Value, dataRng.Columns(2))) '<--| write current name in Sheet2 column "A" current empty cell after last not empty one, and corresponding sum in adjacent cell
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```